# How to make winforms fullscreen app with mono & raspbian?

Tags: c#, mono, raspbian

I've got Raspbian, Mono and C#. The problem is that I can't make my app fullscreen, I can't put away Raspbian panel. There is no problem in Windows, but in Raspbian it does not work. Are there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

For me the following did the trick (Raspbian 3.18.11 and mono 3.12.1):

1. Right click on the taskbar and select "Panel Settings".
2. Go to the "Advanced"-Tab.
3. Uncheck "Reserve space, and not covered by maximised windows".

Also make sure, your form has the following Properties set:

```
ControlBox = false;
FormBorderStyle = None;
WindowState = Maximized;
```